# tftp transfer painfully slow

Tags: networking, udp, tftp

I am using `HPA's tftp server` for `PXE` boot. When I try downloading an image from my tftp server using `curl`, the transfer rate is less than `3 MB/s`, even on my 1Gb network.

```
curl -o initrd.gz tftp://192.168.0.4:69/boot/debian/initrd.gz
```

Is this an inherent limitation of the `tftp` protocol, or can this be configured?

Comment: Same problem here,hpux and solaris tftp are really fast Linux tftp is ultraslow(slackware)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Try to increase the maximum block size on the server (e.g. `--blocksize 1468`).
- Check with server in debug mode, see if there are retransmits.
- Check if you really have Gb connection end-to-end.
- Test on a different client node.
- Check if there is some other problem not related to `tftp` - try `iperf`, `tcpdump`, `ethtool` ...

Comment: setting `--blocksize 1468` on the server alone did not help. I had to specify the block size on the client as well, i.e. `curl --tftp-blksize 1468`. Then I get around `6.5 MB/s`. This still does not seem very impressive. With ftp, I get over `100 MB/s` on the same machines.

Answer (score 2):

TFTP is inherently slow, because it waits for an ACK from the other end after transmitting every block. If your client supports it, you may get more performance by using a TFTP server which supports the [RFC 7440](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7440) extension. The upstream version of `HPA's tftp server` does not, but apparrently [there are some patches to add it](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-support-for-the-tftp-windowsize-option-rfc-7440/8214).